# Insert rows for missing data and interpolate

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, interpolation, missing-data

I have the following data frame in R:

```
        Date Accumulated
1 2016-10-01     6902000
2 2016-11-01     9033000
3 2017-06-01    15033000
4 2017-11-01    24033000
5 2019-05-01    24533000
6 2019-08-01    25033000
7 2019-11-01    27533000
8 2020-06-01    29033000
```

I'm interested in completing with rows for the missing months in the "Data" column while applying a linear or spline interpolation (preferably a spline interpolation) in the "Accumulated" column (i.e., I need rows for 2016-12-01, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, and so on).

I have seen another questions where people recommend using the "zoo" and "data.table" packages where they first create the rows with "NA" and then apply the interpolation... But I'm not sure how to do this because my data is organized differently (all of my Date data is in one column, in contrast to this case for example: [r - insert row for missing monthly data and interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383601/r-insert-row-for-missing-monthly-data-and-interpolate)). However I'm still relatively new to R and managing different types and classes of data is very difficult for me. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The non-preferable `approx` method should be something like: `od <-seq(min(dat$Date), max(dat$Date), by="1 month"); data.frame(approx(dat$Date, dat$Accumulated, xout=od)` - think I've answered this before though, so i'll hunt for a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could help using a spline:

```
library(zoo)

#Data
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17075, 17106, 17318, 17471, 
18017, 18109, 18201, 18414), class = "Date"), Accumulated = c(6902000L, 
9033000L, 15033000L, 24033000L, 24533000L, 25033000L, 27533000L, 
29033000L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "data.frame")

#Create seq of dates
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
dfm <- data.frame(Date=seq(min(df$Date),max(df$Date),by='1 month'))
#Now merge
dfmerged <- merge(dfm,df,by = 'Date',all.x=T)
#Now add interpolation
dfmerged$Interpolation <- na.spline(dfmerged$Accumulated)
```

It will produce:

```
         Date Accumulated Interpolation
1  2016-10-01     6902000       6902000
2  2016-11-01     9033000       9033000
3  2016-12-01          NA      10525685
4  2017-01-01          NA      11534406
5  2017-02-01          NA      12222432
6  2017-03-01          NA      12753035
7  2017-04-01          NA      13289484
8  2017-05-01          NA      13995049
9  2017-06-01    15033000      15033000
10 2017-07-01          NA      16511487
11 2017-08-01          NA      18318181
12 2017-09-01          NA      20285631
13 2017-10-01          NA      22246387
14 2017-11-01    24033000      24033000
15 2017-12-01          NA      25510428
16 2018-01-01          NA      26673271
17 2018-02-01          NA      27548534
18 2018-03-01          NA      28163225
19 2018-04-01          NA      28544352
20 2018-05-01          NA      28718923
21 2018-06-01          NA      28713943
22 2018-07-01          NA      28556422
23 2018-08-01          NA      28273365
24 2018-09-01          NA      27891781
25 2018-10-01          NA      27438677
26 2018-11-01          NA      26941060
27 2018-12-01          NA      26425938
28 2019-01-01          NA      25920317
29 2019-02-01          NA      25451205
30 2019-03-01          NA      25045611
31 2019-04-01          NA      24730540
32 2019-05-01    24533000      24533000
33 2019-06-01          NA      24484346
34 2019-07-01          NA      24633317
35 2019-08-01    25033000      25033000
36 2019-09-01          NA      25709290
37 2019-10-01          NA      26579313
38 2019-11-01    27533000      27533000
39 2019-12-01          NA      28465321
40 2020-01-01          NA      29291385
41 2020-02-01          NA      29931341
42 2020-03-01          NA      30305333
43 2020-04-01          NA      30333510
44 2020-05-01          NA      29936017
45 2020-06-01    29033000      29033000
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to ThomasIsCoding and @Rui Barradas for their answers as well! They helped me to better understand your code and ways to contrast it.

Comment: @caproki Awesome !! Of course all answers contributed to your understanding of interpolation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try `spline` from base R like below

```
xout <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01"), by = "1 month")
yout <- with(df, spline(Date, Accumulated, xout = xout)$y)
setNames(data.frame(xout,yout),names(df))
```

such that

```
> setNames(data.frame(xout,yout),names(df))
         Date Accumulated
1  2016-10-01     6902000
2  2016-11-01     9033000
3  2016-12-01    10482841
4  2017-01-01    11503192
5  2017-02-01    12204935
6  2017-03-01    12705371
7  2017-04-01    13267237
8  2017-05-01    13972655
9  2017-06-01    15033000
10 2017-07-01    16485476
11 2017-08-01    18315168
12 2017-09-01    20307491
13 2017-10-01    22227042
14 2017-11-01    24033000
15 2017-12-01    25477768
16 2018-01-01    26651692
17 2018-02-01    27529507
18 2018-03-01    28091508
19 2018-04-01    28484305
20 2018-05-01    28660790
21 2018-06-01    28660401
22 2018-07-01    28509648
23 2018-08-01    28226152
24 2018-09-01    27840967
25 2018-10-01    27398164
26 2018-11-01    26895893
27 2018-12-01    26393045
28 2019-01-01    25883766
29 2019-02-01    25413112
30 2019-03-01    25044851
31 2019-04-01    24726252
32 2019-05-01    24533000
33 2019-06-01    24484235
34 2019-07-01    24629969
35 2019-08-01    25033000
36 2019-09-01    25718441
37 2019-10-01    26569896
38 2019-11-01    27533000
39 2019-12-01    28443968
40 2020-01-01    29277623
41 2020-02-01    29919811
42 2020-03-01    30273784
43 2020-04-01    30309852
44 2020-05-01    29931563
45 2020-06-01    29033000
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17075, 17106, 17318, 17471, 
18017, 18109, 18201, 18414), class = "Date"), Accumulated = c(6902000L,
9033000L, 15033000L, 24033000L, 24533000L, 25033000L, 27533000L,
29033000L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

The following base R solution uses `approxfun` to create an interpolating function.

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date)

f <- approxfun(df1$Date, df1$Accumulated)
d <- seq(min(df1$Date), max(df1$Date), by = "month")
df2 <- data.frame(Date = d, Accumulated = f(d))
```

To see the result, I will plot the results with package `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(Date, Accumulated)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(Date, Accumulated), colour = "blue")
```

[image]

## Edit

Following the [comment by @ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182156/insert-rows-for-missing-data-and-interpolate/63182314?noredirect=1#comment111727136_63182314), here is a solution with `splinefun`.

```
g <- splinefun(df1$Date, df1$Accumulated)
d <- seq(min(df1$Date), max(df1$Date), by = "month")
df3 <- data.frame(Date = d, Accumulated = g(d))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df3, aes(Date, Accumulated)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(Date, Accumulated), colour = "blue")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
        Date Accumulated
1 2016-10-01     6902000
2 2016-11-01     9033000
3 2017-06-01    15033000
4 2017-11-01    24033000
5 2019-05-01    24533000
6 2019-08-01    25033000
7 2019-11-01    27533000
8 2020-06-01    29033000
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe `splinefun` should be here for OP's preference :)